# Mobile Frequency and Carrier Frequency not Matching

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication, wireless-communication, frequency-response

I am using a Google Nexus 6 Mobile in India with Airtel as Network Provider. Recently Airtel has upgraded their Network to 2300 Mhz 4G. Whereas Google Nexus 6 Operates on Band 3 (1800Mhz) LTE.

When I switch Mobile to LTE Mode - I am able to use 4G Network (Internet ) but there are no Incoming Calls.

When I switch Mobile to 3G Network - I am able to get Incoming Calls but no 4G Network.

What can be the exact cause for this and possible solutions?